# how to define intermediate parameter/variable in Cplex and export solutions to excel/csv?

Tags: variables, export-to-csv, export-to-excel, cplex

some qutsions about cplex intermediate variable define and solutions export need your help.

1. how to define intermediate parameter.

'MC from SheetRead(my_sheet, "SCmodel!b3:m26");  //MC[m][n] is parameters ;'

'how to define parameter EC[m][n], in which EC = 19.6-17*MC; '

2. how to define intermediate variable.

'dvar float+ X[m][n];'

'how to define variable Y[m][n], in which Y = X * MC + MD.....'

3. how to export solutions to excel.  I use ILOG CPLEX in Win10 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about questions 1 and 3 you should use SheetRead and SheetWrite.

Within CPLEX you have a full example at CPLEX_Studio129\opl\examples\opl\oil

about question 2

```
range m=1..4;
range n=1..3;

dvar float+ X[m][n];
dvar float+ Y[m][n];

float MC=1;
float MD=2;

subject to
{
forall(i in m,j in n) Y[i][j]==X[i][j]*MC+MD;
}
```

Comment: great. Do not hesitate to upvote my answer then. Best regards